# Computing average for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array (6 x 6) elements. I want to create another 2D array out of it, where each block is the average of all elements within a blocksize window. Currently, I have the foll. code:

```
import os, numpy

def avg_func(data, blocksize = 2):
    # Takes data, and averages all positive (only numerical) numbers in blocks
    dimensions = data.shape

    height = int(numpy.floor(dimensions[0]/blocksize))
    width = int(numpy.floor(dimensions[1]/blocksize))
    averaged = numpy.zeros((height, width))

    for i in range(0, height):
        print i*1.0/height
        for j in range(0, width):
            block = data[i*blocksize:(i+1)*blocksize,j*blocksize:(j+1)*blocksize]
            if block.any():
                averaged[i][j] = numpy.average(block[block>0])

    return averaged

arr = numpy.random.random((6,6))
avgd = avg_func(arr, 3)
```

Is there any way I can make it more pythonic? Perhaps numpy has something which does it already?

**UPDATE**

Based on M. Massias's soln below, here is an update with fixed values replaced by variables. Not sure if it is coded right. it does seem to work though:

```
dimensions = data.shape 
height = int(numpy.floor(dimensions[0]/block_size)) 
width = int(numpy.floor(dimensions[1]/block_size)) 

t = data.reshape([height, block_size, width, block_size]) 
avrgd = numpy.mean(t, axis=(1, 3))
```

Comment: could you supply an input with expected output? your code is not very self-explanatory ^^

Comment: modified code to be inclusive of sample input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute some operation slice by slice in numpy, it is very often useful to reshape your array and use extra axes.

To explain the process we'll use here: you can reshape your array, take the mean, reshape it again and take the mean again.
Here I assume blocksize is 2

```
t = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],])
t = t.reshape([6, 3, 2])
t = np.mean(t, axis=2)
t = t.reshape([3, 2, 3])
np.mean(t, axis=1)
```

outputs

```
array([[ 0.5,  2.5,  4.5],
       [ 0.5,  2.5,  4.5],
       [ 0.5,  2.5,  4.5]])
```

Now that it's clear how this works, you can do it in one pass only:

```
t = t.reshape([3, 2, 3, 2])
np.mean(t, axis=(1, 3))
```

works too (and should be quicker since means are computed only once - I guess). I'll let you substitute `height/blocksize`, `width/blocksize` and `blocksize` accordingly.

See @askewcan nice remark on how to generalize this to any dimension.

Comment: To generalize beyond 2D (and to let `blocksize` be different along each axis), use `a.reshape(shape).mean(axes)` where `shape = itertools.chain(*np.broadcast(a.shape/blocksize, blocksize))` and `axes = tuple(range(1, 2*a.ndim, 2))`

Comment: thanks! @askewchan, I am getting the foll. error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int', for the line: shape = itertools.chain(*numpy.broadcast(data.shape/block_size, block_size)).

Comment: Oh, sorry, that assumes `blocksize` to be a numpy array.

Comment: Hi M. Massias! Thanks for the solution. I am having a tough time replacing the constants in your solution by the variables. Would this work:     ``dimensions = data.shape
    height = int(numpy.floor(dimensions[0]/block_size))
    width  = int(numpy.floor(dimensions[1]/block_size))

    t = data.reshape([height, block_size, width, block_size])
    avrgd = numpy.mean(t, axis=(1, 3))``

Comment: @user308827 This code works fine for me. What's going wrong, do you get unexpected values, error messages? You can use `//` for integer division instead of calling `np.floor`.

Comment: ok, just wanted to confirm if i was doing the generalization right, thanks!!