# simplify numpy array representation of image

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, image-processing

I have an image, read into `np.array` by PIL.
In my case, it's a`(1000, 1500)` `np.array`.

I'd like to simplify it for visualisation purposes.
By simplification, I following transformation from this matrix

```
1 1 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0
```

to

```
1 1 0
```

so, essentially, look at every `2*2` sample, if it satisfies some criteria, like more than 50% of 1's -> count it as a 1, if not, count is as a 0.

I don't know how to call it properly, but I believe there should be some well known mathematic procedure for doing so.

Comment: the mathematic procedure I think you're talking about is often referred to as "downsampling" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_gallery_of_image_scaling_algorithms) has a little page with a visual comparison of several of the popular methods

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `np.reshape()` and `np.sum(array)` with `axis` argument.:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
a = np.reshape(a, (a.shape[0]/2, 2, a.shape[1]/2, 2))
a = np.sum(a, axis=(1, 3)) >= 2
```

The reshaping groups your array into small 2x2 blocks (the orginals axis lengths must be multiples of 2), I then use sum along the created axis to check that at least of the 4 values in the group is 1.

See [Computing average for numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319036/computing-average-for-numpy-array/32319504#32319504) for similar question.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `>2` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`PIL.Image.fromarray`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) to take the image into PIL, then [resize](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) or convert that image into a [thumbnail](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail) of your desired size. one benefit is this can be easily saved to file, drawn to a canvas, or displayed for debugging. only be aware of numeric types and image modes (a pitfall I often fall into).

creating the image is done by:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.fromarray(arr).astype(np.uint8) #unsigned bytes for 8-bit grayscale
smallerImage = image.resize(desired_size, resample=Image.BILINEAR) #resize returns a copy thumbnail modifies in place
```

Getting the image back to a numpy array is as simple as: `np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(image.size)`